# Change maker icon size in Google Maps API v3.21

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change the size of my marker icons with Google Maps API. Here is my code:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: this.model.get('latitude'), lng: this.model.get('longitude')},
  title: this.model.get('name'),
  icon: {
    url: this.model.get('iconUrl'),
    size: google.maps.Size(50, 50)
  }
});
```

The icon image is naturally 512x512. It is appearing in the correct location on the map, but it is 512x512 instead of 50x50. I've read similar questions and answers for this problem, but none of them seem to address setting the marker size with this version of the API. For example, others use the `MarkerImage` class, but that class no longer exists in this version.

I've also tried including the `scaledSize` property in the icon object, but that doesn't have any effect either.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Here is the 512x512 image I would like to display as 50x50:

[image]

Comment: What is the icon's URL? (or a test icon that has the correct size).

Comment: I added the icon to the post.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `new` here: `size: google.maps.Size(50, 50)` should be `size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)`

Comment: Wow thanks, that was it. However, it also looks like I needed to use `scaledSize` and not use `size` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was missing a `new` and also had to use `scaledSize` instead of `size`. This works for me:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: this.model.get('latitude'), lng: this.model.get('longitude')},
  title: this.model.get('name'),
  icon: {
    url: this.model.get('iconUrl'),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
  }
});
```